# Entity Framework Core include related data from table by string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've built a small application that uses data from a SQL Server database of a third party. They have a structure like this to link their objects together:

A table called 'Objecten' that keeps the most common data, like the ObjectId, Unid, Name, Description, ... All these objects have an 'ObjectType' column, which is a VARCHAR/string like: for example '`VRIJ1OBJECT`', '`VRIJ2OBJECT`', '`HARDWARE`'

The related data is stored in a table with these names: '`VRIJ1OBJECTEN`', '`VRIJ2OBJECTEN`', '`HARDWARE`'.

In my (ASP.NET Core) code, I'm using EF Core 2.0. I try to return a (paged) list of objects with some of their related data, **but I have no idea how to join on a table using a string name.**

So currently, when I'm returning 10 objects for a page, I'm doing 11 queries. 1 to get the 10 objects and 1 for each object to get the related data from the table according to their ObjectType. This takes about 3 seconds, while 1 query only takes about 200ms. The API should be alot faster.

Some code:

```
private async Task<(List<ObjectViewModel> objecten, int totaalAantalObjecten)> _getTopDeskObjectenAsync(string q = null, string sort = "Naam-", int take = 0, int skip = 0, string e = null, bool qall = false, string categorie = "", RolstoelZoekenVM rolstoelZoekenVm = null, bool aotCategorie = false, AotZoekenVM aotZoekenVm = null)
{
    var objecten = await _db.Object.Where(o => o.Status != -1).ToListAsync();

    ... (paging, filtering, ...) ...

    var returnObjecten = new List<ObjectViewModel>();
    foreach (var o in objecten){
        returnObjecten.Add(await _dbObjectToViewModelAsync(o));
    }
    return (returnObjecten, totalCount);
}

private async Task<ObjectViewModel> _dbObjectToViewModelAsync(TopDeskDatabase.Object o)
{
    var vrijObject = await GetDbVrijObjectAsync(o);
    return new ObjectViewModel
    {
        ... filling up the VM properties ...
    }
}

// THIS should be done by the SQL Server in the query
public async Task<IVrijobject> GetDbVrijObjectAsync(TopDeskDatabase.Object o)
{
    switch(o.Type.ToLower())
    {
        case "vrij1object":
                return await _db.Vrij1object.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
            case "vrij2object":
                return await _db.Vrij2object.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
            case "vrij3object":
                return await _db.Vrij3object.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
            case "vrij4object":
                return await _db.Vrij4object.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
            case "vrij5object":
                return await _db.Vrij5object.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
            case "hardware":
                return await _db.Hardware.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
            case "inventaris":
                return await _db.Inventaris.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
            case "telefonie":
                return await _db.Telefonie.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.Objectid == o.Unid);
        }

        throw new InvalidDataException($"Object '{o.RefNaam}' is van type '{o.Type}', welke niet VRIJxOBJECT, INVENTARIS, TELEFONIE of HARDWARE is!");
}
```

Comment: So basically, you have a TPT hierarchy with a custom discriminator but it's not modeled as a type hierarchy in the C# model classes?

Comment: Is the `Unid` unique across all involved tables or would there be the same `Unid` value for different entries when `Type` is different?

Comment: I have no idea what you said in the first comment :) but possibly this is what I have. The Unid is the Unid of the object. The same Unid is in the 'type table'. For example select unid, type from object => {guid: 3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301, type: 'VRIJ1OBJECT' } and select relateddata from vrij1objecten where objectunid = '3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301' => this returns the correct related data for the object

Comment: What @grek40 is saying is that the database tables design seems to be a mixture of [Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) and [Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt). And you are trying to do by hand what EF does automatically when using some of its inheritance strategies. But I guess because of the mixture you can't use EF automatic behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a query with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for each possible return type, store the resulting objects for each type and then compress the data client side by casting to the `IVrijobject`.

See the following example with 2 types (Note I created it with EF6, so there might be some changes required for EF Core)

```
public class ObjectModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ObjectTypeID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ObjectTypeDiscriminator { get; set; }
}

public interface IObjectTypeModel
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Data { get; set; }
}

// ObjectTypeDiscriminator = "Type1"
public class ObjectType1Model : IObjectTypeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

// ObjectTypeDiscriminator = "Type2"
public class ObjectType2Model : IObjectTypeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

class DbC : DbContext
{
    public DbC()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ObjectModel> Objects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ObjectType1Model> Type1Objects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ObjectType2Model> Type2Objects { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Test program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DbC>());

        // initialize some test data
        using (var db = new DbC())
        {
            var t1_1 = db.Type1Objects.Add(new ObjectType1Model { Data = "Object T1 1" });
            var t1_2 = db.Type1Objects.Add(new ObjectType1Model { Data = "Object T1 2" });
            var t2_1 = db.Type2Objects.Add(new ObjectType2Model { Data = "Object T2 1" });
            var t2_2 = db.Type2Objects.Add(new ObjectType2Model { Data = "Object T2 2" });
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Objects.Add(new ObjectModel { ObjectTypeID = t1_1.ID, ObjectTypeDiscriminator = "Type1" });
            db.Objects.Add(new ObjectModel { ObjectTypeID = t1_2.ID, ObjectTypeDiscriminator = "Type1" });
            db.Objects.Add(new ObjectModel { ObjectTypeID = t2_1.ID, ObjectTypeDiscriminator = "Type2" });
            db.Objects.Add(new ObjectModel { ObjectTypeID = t2_2.ID, ObjectTypeDiscriminator = "Type2" });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        // fresh context for query demonstration
        using (var db = new DbC())
        {
            db.Database.Log = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
            var result =
                from o in db.Objects
                join t1 in db.Type1Objects on new { Discriminator = o.ObjectTypeDiscriminator, ObjectTypeID = o.ObjectTypeID } equals new { Discriminator = "Type1", ObjectTypeID = t1.ID } into types1
                join t2 in db.Type2Objects on new { Discriminator = o.ObjectTypeDiscriminator, ObjectTypeID = o.ObjectTypeID } equals new { Discriminator = "Type2", ObjectTypeID = t2.ID } into types2
                from t1 in types1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from t2 in types2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    Obj = o,
                    T1 = t1,
                    T2 = t2,
                };
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                // only one concrete type will have a non-null value
                var T = (IObjectTypeModel)item.T1 ?? item.T2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0,20}{1,20}", item.Obj.ObjectTypeDiscriminator, T.Data);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Opened connection at 06.12.2017 10:25:34 +01:00

SELECT
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Extent1].[ObjectTypeID] AS [ObjectTypeID],
    [Extent1].[ObjectTypeDiscriminator] AS [ObjectTypeDiscriminator],
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1],
    [Extent2].[Data] AS [Data],
    [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID2],
    [Extent3].[Data] AS [Data1]
    FROM   [dbo].[ObjectModels] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ObjectType1Model] AS [Extent2]
        ON ([Extent1].[ObjectTypeDiscriminator] = N'Type1') AND ([Extent1].[ObjectTypeID] = [Extent2].[ID])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ObjectType2Model] AS [Extent3]
        ON ([Extent1].[ObjectTypeDiscriminator] = N'Type2') AND ([Extent1].[ObjectTypeID] = [Extent3].[ID])


-- Executing at 06.12.2017 10:25:34 +01:00

-- Completed in 6 ms with result: SqlDataReader



               Type1         Object T1 1
               Type1         Object T1 2
               Type2         Object T2 1
               Type2         Object T2 2
Closed connection at 06.12.2017 10:25:34 +01:00
```

As you can see, the generated query will use separate result columns for each object, which might or might not be less efficient than merging the result based on a discriminator (I didn't investigate this aspect). If your `Unid` is unique enough, then you don't need the `Discriminator` part of the join condition.

Comment: The question mentioned *"[...] while 1 query only takes about 200ms"* and if we can have a look at the 200ms query, this might be a hint how to design a better query in EF.